# Image Rendition option not available for XsltListViewWebPart

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, xslt-list-view-web-part

I have added my custom image library web part on my default home page programmatically.

Now when I tried in default view of image libary. It shows image rendition option as below:
[image]

It will not show rendition option for XsltListViewWebPart which is as below:

[image]

Is there any way to set image rendition option programmaticaly for XsltListViewWebPart?